# Why doesn't Raspbian apt-get resolve package version correctly?

Tags: apt, software-installation, raspberry-pi, raspbian, debian-installer

I am trying to install a couple of utilities on a RaspberryPi (probably model 3B), but I have problems with the `apt-get` command resolving package versions.

Specifically, trying to install `minicom`, I get the following error. It is similar with 'telnet' and 'putty' as well:

```
$ sudo apt-get install minicom
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lrzsz
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lrzsz minicom
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 317 not upgraded.
Need to get 332 kB of archives.
After this operation, 997 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  lrzsz minicom
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main lrzsz armhf 0.12.21-7
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main minicom armhf 2.7-1+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lrzsz/lrzsz_0.12.21-7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/minicom/minicom_2.7-1+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Following the advice on the error message, I tried updating, but got similar errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

... and also:

```
$ sudo apt-get install minicom --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  lrzsz
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lrzsz minicom
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 317 not upgraded.
Need to get 332 kB of archives.
After this operation, 997 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  lrzsz minicom
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main lrzsz armhf 0.12.21-7
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main minicom armhf 2.7-1+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/l/lrzsz/lrzsz_0.12.21-7_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/minicom/minicom_2.7-1+deb8u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]

E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

When browsing the URLs, it seems like the problem is that `apt-get` looks for older versions of the packages, which are no longer in the repo.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:** From the comments it looks like the way to solve this is to update (reinstall) the OS version. After consulting with the guy responsible for maintaining our setup, it happens that we run many proprietary and legacy pieces on those machines, so it was decided to freeze configuration a while back.

Can I tell `apt-get` to look for the old package versions? If so, where can I find those versions?

Comment: I don't know much about raspbian, but I do know that Debian Jessie is very old (that has been succeded by Stretch, Buster and Bullseye), might this be that raspbian has removed support for their version based on Jessie?

Comment: I have no idea. The question is, can this be fixed, and how? I mean, should this process be automatic?

Comment: If I'm right the way to have prevented it, is to have upgraded that box. For Debian proper Jessie was succeeded by Stretch in 2017. Version upgardes aren't (and shouldn't be) automatic. If this can be fixed now requires a deeper knowledge of raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS than I have,

Comment: Thanks. So you're suggesting updating the OS itself?

Comment: Raspberry pi jessie has been unsupported for years - yes, you need to update to at least Buster (so called "legacy" by Raspberry Pi foundation) - Bullseye was released largely untested it seems, so stick to Buster. Also, you can't "update" - Raspberry Pi Foundation do not support updating major releases - you need to install the new OS, then re-install/reconfigure everything from scratch - that's not a Debian fault, that's purely due to the ineptitude of Raspberry Pi Foundation

Comment: Having said that, I've successfully updated wheezy -> jessie -> stretch -> buster -> bullseye on a pi - though, I (unlike Upton and his team of noobs) know what I'm doing.

Comment: try pinging those ips to check if they are accessible inside your network.

Comment: They are accessible, the problem is with the specific files targeted.

Answer (score 1):

As found [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=237469), you must replace every occurrence of archive.raspberrypi.org or mirrordirector.raspbian.org by legacy.raspbian.org, which is an official site.

Comment: This fixed my "apt-get update" error and now I can install the missing packages. Just had to change "mirrordirector" to "legacy". Allowed me to update my bluetooth